# Probability Help

Tags: statistics

According to the American Red Cross, approximately 10% of the human population is blood type B-positive. If we select 20 people at random, find the probability that more than 3 people in the sample have blood type B-positive. Is this unusual? n=4 p=.5

Comment: Look up the binomial distribution

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: what's the probability that if you select 20 people at random, 3 or less people in the sample have blood type B-positive?